# Stuck with Custom Android Listview

Tags: android

I have an app that loads images from a database into a ScrollView. I want to change it to ListView.

Here is what I have now:

Every line in the ListView should be inflated from this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                <ImageButton  
                    android:background="@drawable/roundcorners"
                    android:id="@+id/figura" 
                    android:src="@drawable/rice"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="84dip" 
                    android:layout_width="98dip"
                    android:gravity="left">
                </ImageButton>
                <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:gravity="left"
                   android:layout_weight="1">
                   <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="Rice"
                        android:id="@+id/txtNome"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="30dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                   <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="rice, food"
                        android:id="@+id/txtTags"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

It's basically an image, its name and its tags.

**I just updated the code below to reflect SLUKIAN's suggestion:**

```
public class AnotherCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public AnotherCursorAdapter(Context context, 
                                int layout, 
                                Cursor c,
                                String[] from, 
                                int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
             // get the views from the row
             TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
             TextView tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);
             ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.figura);
            //asign the values
             name.setText(cursor.getString(4)); // the number will be the index of the column containing the name
             tags.setText(cursor.getString(3)); // the same thing
             // set the image resource, i don't know how you stored it in the database
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imgsinternas, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

After getting my info inside the cursor (from database) in my activity, I am doing this:

```
                    AnotherCursorAdapter adapter = new AnotherCursorAdapter(CadItemActivity.this, 
                                                                            R.layout.imgsinternas, 
                                                                            cursorImagens, 
                                                                            new String[] {cursorImagens.getString(4), cursorImagens.getString(3)/*your columns from the cursor*/},
                                                                            new int[] { R.id.txtNome, R.id.txtTags });
                    telaScroll.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**When I run the suggested code I get the following error:**

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'id' does not exist**

Slukian, did I make anything wrong? Can you help me, please?

**I am having a REALLY hard time to use a ListView with the code above. I am kind of lost.**

How do I set my cursor (cursorImagens) to be the ListView's adapter?

How do I set the image, the name and the tags (these are the three infos that come from my database)?

Hey guys... I have seen lots of tutorials, but most of them are the simple kind, just a simple list.

Can anyone help me, please?

Any help is appreciatted!

Comment: see this [link](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/listview-data-sqlitedatabase) hope fully this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit from `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override getView (or newView and bindView) method(s).
Here's a good tutorial on ListViews and adapters - http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

You should also watch Romain Guy's (ListView's author) speech at Google IO called [`The world of ListView`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).

Comment: Hello Vladimir, thank you for you answer. Any sample code? I am a noob in this! =/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement your own adapter, you could extend a `SimpleCursorAdapter` because you have a cursor with data:

```
public class AnotherCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AnotherCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
             // get the views from the row
             TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
             TextView tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);
             ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.figura);
            //asign the values
             name.setText(cursor.getString(0)); // the number will be the index of the column containing the name
             tags.setText(cursor.getString(1)); // the same thing
             // set the image resource, i don't know how you stored it in the database
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_layout_you_have, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity after you fetch the data use this adapter for your list:

```
AnotherCursorAdapter adapter = new AnotherCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.test_row, cursor, new String[] {/*your columns from the cursor*/},
                new int[] { R.id.txtNome, R.id.txtTags });
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hello Slukian, your code seems to be very close to what I need. Thank you very much. However, now when I run it, I get another error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'id' does not exist. I updated the code above with your suggestion. Can you help me by saying what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much! =^)

Comment: @CarlosPereira The adapters that are based on a `Cursor` need to have a special column in the database like this `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. When you query the database add this column to the query besides other column that you need(although you don't need the data it must be present or you get that exception). Also when you create the adapter the forth parameter should be an array of string with the names of the columns from the database(like column1, column2)(right now you are getting strings from the cursor instead of the column names)